# How to fix the code to display data on EditText using GET method, myjson url

Tags: c#, api, sql-server-2012, xamarin.android, json.net

I'm trying to display my data from myjson API on edittext after clicking a button but unfortunately the data did not display on the edit text instead a black box appeared once i clicked on the button. I'm trying to retrieve the data from local SQL Server to Xamarin.Android. I hope you can help me solve my problems. Thank you!

**code PersonalInfoActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace CatcityPark
{
    [Activity(Label = "Account Info", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
    public class PersonalInfoActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PersonalInfo);

            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            Button btnGetAcc = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGetAcc);

            btnGetAcc.Click += BtnGetAcc_Click;
        }

        private async void BtnGetAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditText email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            EditText firstName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
            EditText lastName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtLastName);
            EditText gen = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtGender);
            EditText ic = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtIC);
            EditText address = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAddress);
            EditText phoneNo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo);
            EditText username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
            EditText password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPwd);
            EditText payment = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPayMethod);

            VehicleRecord vehicRec = null;
            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.myjson.com/bins/13z38c" + email.Text.ToString());
            string contactsJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //VehicleRecordList objVehicRecList = new VehicleRecordList();
            try
            {
                vehicRec = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehicleRecord>(contactsJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            if (vehicRec == null)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, contactsJson, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                firstName.Text = vehicRec.firstName;
                lastName.Text = vehicRec.lastName;
                gen.Text = vehicRec.gender;
                ic.Text = vehicRec.icNo;
                address.Text = vehicRec.address;
                phoneNo.Text = vehicRec.phoneNo;
                username.Text = vehicRec.username;
                password.Text = vehicRec.password;
                payment.Text = vehicRec.paymentMethod;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**code for VehicleRecord.cs**

```
public class VehicleRecord
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string icNo { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string phoneNo { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string plateNo { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string col { get; set; }
        public string paymentMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

The expected result should display all the data from SQL Server unfortunately it didn't show.

Comment: did you receive the correct data by calling the api ? You may put a break-point and see if you get the data at all, then check for some ui blocking thing that prevents the text to be modified.

Comment: Do you mean the get method display the correct data after calling the api? Am i correct?

Comment: Yes. Do you get the correct data

Comment: Yes, I get the correct data but it didn't display on the edit text :(

Comment: Take a look at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7185/assign-a-text-to-a-edittext

Comment: Let me try first. I'll let u know later @BabakFakhriloo

Comment: Nope still couldn't display the text. When I clicked on the button a black box appears on the screen. I don't know why? How should i fix it in order to display the data @BabakFakhriloo

Answer (score 0):

> black box appeared once i clicked on the button

It appears that the black box is the Toast with empty string.
I mean this piece of code:

```
if (vehicRec == null)
 {
     Toast.MakeText(this, contactsJson, ToastLength.Short).Show();
 }
```

So check first of the response is successful and try to debug it..

Comment: i've solve the problem. its bcs of my url but unfortunately the data still not appear on the edit text :(